# How to know or retrieve the sender id

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have the following method

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender {

}
```

and would like to be able to know the sender id.

e.g. if there are multiple buttons linked to this method, I would like to know which button was pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sender tag]

I don't know what you mean by "id" (the "sender" is an id, effectively an NSObject *), but you could use tags. You have to set the tag beforehand in Interface Builder or programmatically.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use the tag property, inherited from UIView, which is a NSInteger, in a switch statement, or using if conditions.

The tag property can be set in your code, or through InterfaceBuilder.

Answer (score 3):

If you have set up IBOutlets for the buttons in your interface then you can simply compare the sender to those.

That is in your interface definition if you have

```
...
  (IBOutlet) UIButton *button1;
  (IBOutlet) UIButton *button2;
...
```

and in your implementation you have:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
  if (sender == button1) {
    ....
  }
  else if (sender == button2) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Personally, I'd prefer to use different action methods for each button and then they can all call a common routine for the things that are common. However, for simple projects the above will work.

-J

Answer (score 0):

Set the `tag` property of each button to a unique integer (either in IB or programmatically) and switch on it inside your action method.

Comment: @user397363: He said "switch *on it*", meaning check the tag and do different things depending on what it is.